Function to build back a function when using fft?
In python and in numpy, there are several packages to obtain the FFTs. However, is there a function in numpy or in another package such that, if one feeds the Fourier coefficients from the FFT, it gives back the original "fitted" function?
For instance, if I sample a $\sin(x_j)$ in, say, 50 points, I could reconstruct the function using the Fourier coefficients in, say 100 points.

Numpy has inverse FFT functions like this one. Is one of those what you are looking for? If not, how do they differ from what you are looking for?

It's always good to put in the effort of using google first...

@EricPostpischil I was thinking more in the reconstruction of a general (noisy) data for which one wants to find a Fourier series that roughly describes it. The sine function was not really a good example, sorry for it.
So the fft gives the coefficients of the Fourier series. What I am looking for is the function for which you can feed these coefficients but leave undertermined the independent variable "t", if f(t) is represented specifically as a real Fourier series.

I can recommend this answer. If you are more interested in denoising and not in the fft approach, then check my answer using GPR in the same questiom @user2820579

Numpy offers inverse fft function numpy.fft.ifft. You can use it to reconstruct a function using frequency terms:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,50,501)
sine_wave = np.sin(x)
fft_sine_wave = np.fft.fft(sine_wave)
ifft_sine_wave = np.fft.ifft(fft_sine_wave)

plt.plot(x, sine_wave, label='sine wave')
plt.plot(x, ifft_sine_wave, '--', label='ifft reconstruction')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

With the output being a reconstruction of the original sine signal.

Well, almost. Please see my comment above, in response to Eric
